# How do you get everything under the root element?

Tags: lxml, elementtree

I'm using etree to clean up some html. I realise that I have to have a root tag to hold all the elements, but I want to return the string without the root. Is there any way to do this.

```
from lxml import etree

fragment = etree.fromstring("<fragment>text1 <a>tex2 </a>text3<b>text4</b> <c>text 5</c>text 6<span style=''> Style</span></fragment>")
delete_tag = 'delete_me'
for element in fragment.xpath(".//span[@style='']"):
  element.tag = delete_tag
etree.strip_tags(fragment, delete_tag)
print(etree.tostring(fragment))
```

What I get is

```
b'<fragment>text1 <a>tex2 </a>text3<b>text4</b> <c>text 5</c>text 6 Style</fragment>'
```

but I want is

```
text1 <a>tex2 </a>text3<b>text4</b> <c>text 5</c>text 6 Style
```

Comment: You get your target as a string but you can't load that sting into etree because that string is not valid html.

Comment: @JackFleeting Hi. The string does load and the output renders to string as shown in the above 'what I get' example. Are you saying you can't output what I want because that isn't valid because it isn't wrapped in a single root tag?

Comment: Exactly; the output of "what I get" is valid html. The "what I want" is not valid html - if you try to load it using `fromstring()` without wrapping it in a single root tag, you'll get an error. So it depends on what you want do with the "what I want" string - if you want to treat it as an html element, you'll have to wrap it. If you just need a string, that can be easily done.

Comment: So there is no way to output to string the children of the 'fragment' element? oh. bugg*r.

Comment: Yes, there is (I can post in an answer if you're interested - too long for comment); but it will just be a string, not a valid html element.

Comment: I'm dealing with HTML fragments that are saved and inserted elsewhere so they might start with a string or an element. It would be a massive help and you might save what remaining hair I have left.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something along these lines:

```
elems = fragment.xpath('.//*')
target = ''
target+=(fragment.xpath('./text()[1]')[0])
for elem in elems:
    target+=(etree.tostring(elem).decode())
target
```

Output:

```
'text1 <a>tex2 </a>text3<b>text4</b> <c>text 5</c>text 6 Style'
```